# ObjectOutputStream writeObject hangs when two clients send objects to server

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I am writing client/server application in which multiple clients connect to servers and continiusly send serialized objects to servers at a high rate over TCP connection.

I am using ObjectOutputStream.writeObject on client and ObjectInputStream.readObject at server.

Server application accepts clients connection on the single port using serverSocket.accept() and passes Socket to a new thread for reading objects.

When a single client connects and sends about 25K objects/s - all works fine. Once I start a second client, after the short period of time, one or both clients hang on ObjectOutputStream.writeObject for one of the servers and the corresponding server hangs on the ObjectInputStream.readObject. 
No exceptions thrown on the both sides.

If rate is very low, lets say 10-20/s in total - it will not hang but at 100-1000/s it will.

Using `netstat -an` on the client machine I can see that the `send-Q` of the corresponding link is about 30K. On the server side the `receive-Q` is also ~30K.

When running client/server on the local Windows I observe something similar - client hangs but the server continue to process incoming objects and once it catches up, client unlocks and continue to send objects.

Locally on windows the server is slower than client, but on linux, number of the server instances running on the deferent machines is more than enough for the rate that clients produce.

Any clue what is going on?

client code snip:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(address, port);
ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
while(true)
{
     IMessage msg = createMsg();
     outputStream.writeObject(msg);
     outputStream.flush();
     outputStream.reset();
}
```

server code accepting connections:

```
while(active)
{
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    SocketThread socketThread = new SocketThread(socket);
    socketThread.setDaemon(true);
    socketThread.start();
}
```

server code reading objects:

```
public class SocketThread extends Thread 
    {
        Socket socket;
        public SocketThread(Socket socket)
        {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                while(true)
                {
                    IMessage msg = (IMessage)inStream.readObject();
                    if(msg == null){
                        continue;
                    }
                    List<IMessageHandler> handlers = handlersMap.get(msg.getClass());
                    for(IMessageHandler handler : handlers){
                        handler.onMessage(msg);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: NB `readObject()` won't return null unless you send a null. If you're not planning on doing that, the null test is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You have just described the operation of TCP when the sender outruns the receiver. The receiver tells the sender to stop sending, so the sender stops sending. As you are using blocking I/O, the client blocks in `send()` internally.

There is no problem here to solve.

Comment: No, it does not. Servers happily process 25K/s with single client, but freezes on 1K/s with two.

Comment: So you have a concurrency problem at the server.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that handlers on the server side were using some not thread-safe resources (like Jedis connection) so it was all stack on the server side.

Doing it thread safe solved the issue.

Comment: So you had a concurrency problem at the server, exactly as I stated 21 months ago.

Comment: So why are you telling us something I already told you 21 months ago?

Comment: Found for you some forum whe you can discass this http://www.socialanxietysupport.com/forum/f24/human-behaviour-2122330/#/forums/3